# Spyder omitting index on dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, anaconda

I am coding in python using spyder of anaconda navigator and I have created a dataframe from a file and performed:

```
df2=df1[df1.pu != ef]
df=df2[df2.energy != enmin ]
df2=None
df.to_csv(r'~/Dropbox/data/anand/surface/scan/7/relaxed/dos/df', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Why does it does not show the indexes 1,2 and skip directly to 3. I do not understand what it could be.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the rows have been dropped and you didn't reset the index with `df.reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: yes thak you very much, I actaully did and forgot to mention! It solved my issue, I was not aware of this

Answer (score 0):

After the rows have been dropped use:

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Credit to Chris Greening